# How can I override system time

Tags: smali

I thought this should be be simple enough, but I can't figure it out. For testing purposes, I want to set an exact output in the function below. For example, I want V2 (wide) to equal 1349333576093 everytime. Normally, I would just put a line underneath saying "const v2, 0x1" etc but since it's wide, I am not sure how to do this. Any help please?

```
invoke-static {}, Ljava/lang/System;->currentTimeMillis()J
move-result-wide v2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const-wide is what you want.

```
const-wide v2, 1349333576093L
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion but got a build error: "cannot fit into an int"